# Manipulating an inequality:

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove that if $a>1$ $x,y>0$, and there is $b$ such that $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = 1$ then xy $\leq \frac{x^a}{a} + \frac{y^b}{b}$

I have made several attempts, but I get to no answer. Is there any inequality that needs to be shown before?

Comment: Check out Holder's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an elementary proof. Fix $y>0$ and let $f(x)= \frac {x^{a}} a+\frac {y^{b}} b-xy$. Then $f'(x) <0$ for $x <y^{1/(a-1)}$ and $f'(x) >0$ for $x >y^{1/(a-1)}$. It follows that $f$ decreases up to $x =y^{1/(a-1)}$ and then increases. So its minimum  value is attained when $x =y^{1/(a-1)}$. A simple computation shows that $f(x)=0$ when $x =y^{1/(a-1)}$. Hence $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ which is the given inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are looking for is Young's inequality for products. Let $a, b >0$. Then, let $t = 1/a$ and $1-t = 1/b$. Then $$x^a / a + y^b / b = tx^a + (1-t)y^b .$$

Taking the natural log of the righthand side of the expression, we get $$\ln(tx^a + (1-t)y^b) \geq t\ln(x^a) +(1-t)\ln(y^b) = \ln(x) + \ln(y) = \ln(xy).$$

Exponentiating both sides of this give the desired relation.